# SQL Calling Columns in Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So I would like to preface that this IS an assignment for school, but I'm not asking for the answer, I'm just wondering if there is a way to call upon columns from a temporary/renamed table. Also, I'm wondering if a subquery or some other technique would be better suited/if I'm on the right track. 
The context of my code is that we have a table 'sailors' with columns 'sname,' 'age,' 'rating,' and 'sid (which seems irrelevant for this particular question)'

I'm to find the names of the sailors older than the oldest sailor with a rating of 3. Here's what I have currently, it's probably rough. Thanks!

```
select *, max(age)
from sailors as ThreeStarGeriatric
where rating = 3 
union
select *
from sailors 
where sailors.age > ThreeStarGeriatric.age;
```

Comment: [Google-fu](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/adssql/using_temporary_tables_in_sql_statements.htm) is your 2nd best resource for coding. Also, try your code and tell us the error you get. I bet you it'll give you a great error code that will set you on the right path. Also, [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) exists now. Wish I had that when I was in school

Comment: You can use HAVING, but it's not a good idea.

Comment: Try thinking about your question in Query speak... select name from sailor where age is greater than select age of oldest sailor where rating = 3

Comment: Points for humor `ThreeStarGeriatric`

Comment: Thanks guys! ^  G B, I used a subquery with those constraints. It pretty much looked like what mech posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you COULD use a subquery:

```
SELECT sname FROM sailors WHERE age > (SELECT MAX(age) FROM sailors WHERE Rating=3)
```

"names of the sailors older than the oldest sailor with a rating of 3"

Comment: Thanks for the help, the thought to use a subquery in the where clause didn't occur to me until after I'd posted. It seems obvious now, haha.